# Issue while backpropagating through sparse_tensor_dense_matmul in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a simple network defined as follows:

```
h1 = tf.sparse_tensor_dense_matmul(x, W1)
h2 = tf.matmul(h1, W2)
y = tf.matmul(h2, W3)
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(y - y_)
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=lr).minimize(loss)
```

where x is a `sparseTensor`, rest are dense.

Dimensions (shapes) of W1 = `[1000,200]`, W2 = `[200,400]` and W3 = `[400, 500]`.

When I run the following:

```
sess.run([train], feed_dict={x:X, y_:Y})
```

where `X` is `sparseTensor` of shape `[N, 1000]` and `Y` is a tensor of shape `[N, 500]`

I get an error saying:

> OOM when allocating tensor with shape[3684773,200].

This is happening while the the the gradient for `W` is being computed. 3684773 also happens to be the number of non-zero elements in `X`.

Note:

1. When I compute gradients using `tf.gradients`, they work completely
   fine.
2. When I run the same network using dense `X` and dense `multiply( tf.matmul )`, it works completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm a bit late to help you, but the problem you face is that you do not have enough memory to allocate the tensor for the gradient. Assuming you're working with 32 bit floats, this tensor would need ~2.8 GB of memory, which is quite a lot for graphics cards. The only solution that I see is to pin everything to CPU memory using

```
with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
    # your code
```

But then you should expect a large performance penalty.